# How to connect an ESP32 Heltec LoRa (v3) to a 2.8" TFT SPI display?

Tags: esp32, lora

How do I connect the large 2.8" TFT SPI display with the "ESP32 Heltec LoRa V3" in order to also receive the display/output from the OLED display on the 2.8" TFT SPI display?

I'm trying to wire a Heltec ESP32 LoRa with integrated OLED display to a TFT-SPI display. Which pins do I have to wire? On the TFT display side I have the pins: SDO/MISO, SDI/MOSI, LED, SCK, DC, RST, CS.